# Reporting results of summary "value" estimate with interaction and nested variables

Tags: r

I created a model:

```
mod1 <- lme(plant.height ~ light * nitrogen * greenhouse.temp)
```

where `plant.height` and `greenhouse.temp` are continuous, `light` is a categorical variable with 2 possibilities (Hi or Lo), and `nitrogen` is a variable with 3 possibilities (Hi, Med, or Lo).

I then use the summary function `summary(mod1)`.  The output is:

```
                                                Value  Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)                                 0.6619078 0.03361541 4696 19.690610  0.0000
lightLo                                    -0.0365087 0.05003933  250 -0.729600  0.4663
nitrogenLo                                  0.0581356 0.04778206  250  1.216682  0.2249
nitrogenMed                                -0.0011590 0.04880369  250 -0.023749  0.9811
greenhouse.temp                             0.0014754 0.00135246  250  1.090904  0.2764
lightLo:nitrogenLo                          0.0535797 0.06932005  250  0.772932  0.4403
lightLo:nitrogenMed                         0.1000916 0.07165606  250  1.396834  0.1637
lightLo:greenhouse.temp                     0.0016099 0.00199813  250  0.805693  0.4212
nitrogenLo:greenhouse.temp                 -0.0013249 0.00190570  250 -0.695228  0.4876
nitrogenMed:greenhouse.temp                 0.0001040 0.00194922  250  0.053339  0.9575
lightLo:nitrogenLo:greenhouse.temp         -0.0020981 0.00276084  250 -0.759949  0.4480
lightLo:nitrogenMed:greenhouse.temp        -0.0044355 0.00285551  250 -1.553322  0.1216
```

I now want to report the estimate and standard error results in a table. So for "light" I report -0.0365(estimate) & 0.0500(SE), for green house temperature  0.00148(estimate) & 0.00135(SE), for the interaction between light and greenhouse temp 0.00161(estimate) & 0.00200(SE). But for "nitrogen," which of the two estimates and SEs do I use? For the interaction between "nitrogen" and "light" there are two estimates and SEs as well, same for the interaction between "nitrogen and greenhouse temp" and for the interaction between "light," "nitrogen," and "greenhouse temp."

Comment: You should report all of the coefficient estimates and standard errors printed out by summary, not just some subset of them.  I recommend you review a statistics resource on interactions in regression. [This](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/Joseph/courses/EPIB-621/interaction.pdf) is from the first page of google results and looks relatively informative on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dan Y. I thought you might say that. I was thinking last night that since the individual estimates show how far they are from the intercept, that there wouldn't be just one coefficient to report for nitrogen or anything interacting with nitrogen (like you said). So I guess for this global model, I wouldn't report estimates or SE for anything with nitrogen (if I wanted to report just one coefficient for each term), but rather, I would make models for each nitrogen level, do a summary, and then report those coefficients. I think I'm starting to understand.